# Multiple HTML5 canvas animations

Tags: angularjs, html, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have multiple HTML `canvas` elements inside different AngularJS directives. Each of these elements are animated using `requestAnimationFrame`.

1. How about the performance? Is it okay to call `requestAnimationFrame` for each `canvas`/`directive` or is using one `service` with `callback` functions to all render functions a better approach?
2. Before the content can be drawn, there are a lot of calculations done inside the render function. For each frame these calculations are necessary. Should this be done before the `requestAnimationFrame` call or is it okay to have a huge amount of calculations after this call?

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` will get all requests done for the same frame, though I am not sure what the order of the requests will be. I assume they come in the same order as they were requested.

The difference between multiple frame requests or a single frame request calling multiple functions is marginal. It would be a style choice not a performance choice.

If the calculations are required for each render frame then there is no advantage to have them run independently of the frame request as you will have to find a way to keep them in sync which would add overhead. If they are not frame dependent then it would be best to do them at whatever rate that will keep the app running smoothly.

Comment: According to [some tests](https://jsfiddle.net/c3wue8pf/) I did, it seems that all raf are even mixed in a single one (they all share the same time argument). The calling order seems to be respected in FF and Chrome. When a frame is dropped, the whole call is also dropped.

Comment: now, to better fit OP needs, maybe he should check whether all the animations really need to be updated at each frame : if some are out of the screen, maybe the rendering can be omitted, and the updates be made time dependent instead of incremental ;  if the calculations are heavy, maybe webworkers can help ; etc.